# Structuring div 's created by "createElement" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, structure

Structuring div's in HTML goes like this:

```
<div id="parentdiv">
     <div id="childdiv"></div>
</div>
```

My code bellow creates 2 divs, but places the child div next to the parent div instead of inside it:

```
var pardiv = document.createElement('pardiv');
pardiv.setAttribute('id', "workspace");
pardiv.innerHTML = "Hello World";
pardiv.style.background = "red";
pardiv.width = 300;
pardiv.height = 300;
document.body.appendChild(pardiv);

var childdiv = document.createElement('childdiv');
    childdiv.setAttribute('id', "childdiv");
    childdiv.innerHTML = "Hello World";
    childdiv.style.background = "yellow";
    childdiv.width = 100;
    childdiv.height = 100;
    document.body.appendChild(childdiv);
```

How can a programmer structure div's like in HTML if they are created through JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't append the childDiv to the body, instead, append it to the parent element like so:

```
pardiv.appendChild(childdiv);
```

Using that, you should be able to set up the same structure as you would in HTML.